# Auto-wrap title through *.sty file

Tags: titles, wrap

I'm beginning to write my personal *.sty file and I would like it to be able to automatically wrap the document title in case it's too long (I'm not sure whether "wrap" is the correct term: I mean to automatically display it on more than one line if need be).

My *.sty file looks like this (I'm not a TeX\LaTeX expert, so it's based on another *.sty file with some slight modifications):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% Some code
\newcommand{\@titolo}{Senza Titolo}
\newcommand{\titolo}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titolo}{#1}}
\renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}
% Some code

{\vfil
    \begin{LARGE}
    {\bf\renewcommand{\\}{\cr}
    \halign{\hbox to\textwidth{\strut\hfil##\hfil}\cr
    \@titolo\cr}}
\end{LARGE}}

% Some code
\end{titlepage}
\endinput
```

So, the question is: is there a way to automatically display the title on more than one line? I've tried by inserting `\@titolo` inside a `\minipage` but wasn't able to succeed. Any kind of help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, `\bf` is obsolete for more than twenty years. Redefining `\\ ` doesn't seem like a good idea either. `LARGE` is not an environment. `hbox`es cannot be broken in differente lines. Personally, i would not base my package on that package you are using.

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: where did the code you start from come from? `\vfil` does nothing in that position, `\bf` shouldn't be used in latex (it's not defined by default) and  using a primitive `\halign` rather than a latex construct such as tabular will have weird side effects. The title would wrap automatically if you did not put it in the halign.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've rewritten the code using a `tabular` environment and it worked out just fine. The code dated back to 2006, but I didn't expect it to be obsolete, thanks for letting me know. @Johannes_B, I'll definetly take a look at that link in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Seems silly to answer to my own question, but as a reference I'll write a working solution that I was able to write thanks to the help received through the comments and some research on [LaTeX book by wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX). I simply substituted the `{\vfil ...}` part with a `\tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}>{\bfseries}>{\huge}p{1\textwidth}<{\centering}}
    \@titolo
\end{tabular}
```

The title (`\@titolo`) wraps just fine and it is bold.

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_title_to_be_re-used_multiple_times. There is absolutely no need to use a tabular environment with a parbox inside. All this gets you is a warning if you are in the wrong place.

Comment: That gives me the possibility of choosing the width of the title, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does. Using the parbox. The tabular isn't needed at all. If the linewidth is equal to textwidth, the parbox isn't needed as well.